# Телега-бот на Python, формы команд для бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как сейчас возможно реализовать формы кнопок в чат-боте, какие библиотеки для этого существуют? чтобы при нажатии на форме предоставленных команд была отправка команд вот в примерном виде? т.е. не писать команды через / , а при нажатии на предоставленной форме отправлять.
P.S. Вариант через клавиатуру не подходит(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это `inline-keyboard`. Реализовать можете через библиотеку `telebot`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Inline keyboard
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'uiscreateemail':
        email_create_request_domain(call.message)  # при нажатии на кнопку выполнится функция email_create_request_domain

    elif call.data == 'uisblock':
        uis_request_data_block(call.message)

    elif call.data == 'uissearch':
        uis_request_data_search(call.message)
```

и сама клавиатура

```
        uis_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        uis_create = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Создать', callback_data='uiscreate')
        uis_block = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Уволить', callback_data='uisblock')
        uis_search = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Найти', callback_data='uissearch')
        uis_back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='other')
        uis_keyboard.add(uis_create, uis_block)
        uis_keyboard.add(uis_search, uis_back)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Выберите:',
                              reply_markup=uis_keyboard)
```